# flow status stucks at Please wait. Server is starting up:

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I was following steps from the documentation https://flow.org/en/docs/install/
but at the end of steps when I ran command `npm run flow` after running `npm run flow init`. My server has stuck at `Please wait. Server is starting up: /`

.flowconfig is default

Comment: Can you try adding this line under your `[ignore]`. `.*node_modules/.*` so that it speeds up server startup and see if it helps? Also what flow-bin version are you running?

Comment: flow version is 0.154.0 and I have added *node_modules/.* at [ignore] but still no solution. is there something missing in the official documentation?
I have followed all things from the documentation itself

Comment: To be clear, did you add `.*node_modules/.*` or `node_modules/.`? There is a difference here and I just want to make sure of what you've done. Also, maybe a restart could help if flow decided to hang you can do this with `npx flow stop && npx flow`

Comment: yes it is ```.*node_modules/.*```. I  have tried with flow stop and flow again but still the same issue

Comment: Last thing to do is to verify if it's just your machine or your project. Are you able to spin up a sample git repro where you get the same issue and I can try to run it myself?

Comment: already did that I have created a new project from scratch and tried to do things from documentation

Comment: Can you link that repo here so I can try it?